# How to change email account on Concent screen of Google Cloud Console?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-plus, google-cloud-console

I am stuck. I have created this app for some time already. At that point I just used my account. Now I'd like present a user with a different email that corresponds to system support email. Is there a way to change it?

[image]

UPDATE: please see my comment. It's all about *currently* logged in user, nothing else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to change the email associated with your project, you must first add another account with the email you want set as the primary email to your owners. This is set in Permissions > Add Member.

After you have added another user to the permissions, they must then access the project in order to set their email as the project's email address.

Comment: I have like 6 emails registered but apparently I missed one important thing - it's possible to change to address of *currently* logged in user, not admin or owner or whatsoever. So I added several but never cared to log in as them. I am accepting the answer nonetheless.