# How to add to the Google Cloud Console Consent Screen email address drop-down?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-console

The "Consent screen" (under "APIs & auth") for an app on the Google Cloud Console shows only my email address in the drop-down.  How do I add other addresses to that, for example a "support@example.com" address?  Is it important?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change email account on Concent screen of Google Cloud Console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463936/how-to-change-email-account-on-concent-screen-of-google-cloud-console)

Answer (score 0):

The list of email addresses are from the project Permissions, to use support@example.com you would first need to add it to the project permissions.

Comment: What is the use of this field?  Is it important?